# Как сделать из числа 03 строку "03"?

Tags: php

Есть цикл по элементам массива. Как из числа 03 сделать строку "03", а не "3"?

```
$arr = ['item1', 03, 'item2', 333];
foreach($arr as $item) {
    echo (string)$item . ' ';
}
```

result: item1 3 item2 333

Comment: Но ведь в памяти компьютера числа 003, 03 и 3 сей равно будут представлены одинаково. Можно лишь получить строку с определённым количеством цифр числа, ставя явные нули в свободные разряды.

Comment: @AivanF., и [ссылочку](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/178988) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно добавлять нули до двух позиций оператором [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php):

```
$arr = ['item1', 3, 'item2', 333];
foreach($arr as $item) {
    if( is_int($item)) printf( '%02d ', $item);
    else printf( '%s ', $item);
}
// item1 03 item2 333
```